# Multiple array rows split in to table header and table rows in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have an array with the following structure.

```
0: "﻿ID,NAME,NUMBER,DESCRIPTION"
1: "123,"PHILIP",0123456789,"OFFICE ADDRESS"
2: "456,"SARA",30345004698,"OFFICE SPACE""
```

I need to display it in a table. The table header will be the 0th row and remaining rows will be the table body rows (tr). Please help me to achieve this.

I can display the table header but table body is not coming properly.

Table is displaying like below [image: this.]

Please find below my code

```js
tableArray: any;
tableArrayRows: any[] = [];
tableHeader: any;
tableRows: any[] = [];

//Splitting the array at new line
this.tableArray =  this.detailsArray.split(/\r?\n/);
//Table header row
this.tableHeader = this.tableArray[0].split(',');
//Table body row
for(var i = 1; i < this.tableArray.length; i ++){
   this.tableArrayRows.push(this.tableArray[i]);
   this.tableRows =  this.tableArrayRows.split(',');
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
      <tr> 
         <th *ngFor="let tableHeaders of tableHeader">{{tableHeaders}}</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr> 
      <td *ngFor="let tableRows of tableRows">{{ tableRows }}</td>
    </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the expected output [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bdpsn7?file=src/app/app.component.css)

in component,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  tableArray: any;
  tableArrayRows: any[] = [];
  tableHeader: any;
  tableRows: any[] = [];
  detailsArray :any= `"ID,NAME,NUMBER,DESCRIPTION"
  "123,"PHILIP",0123456789,"OFFICE ADDRESS"
  "456,"SARA",30345004698,"OFFICE SPACE""`;

  ngOnInit() {

    // Splitting the array at new line
    this.detailsArray = this.detailsArray.replaceAll('"','');
    this.tableArray = this.detailsArray.split(/\r?\n/);
    // Table header row
    this.tableHeader = this.tableArray[0].split(',');
    // Table body row
    this.tableRows = this.tableArray.splice(1, this.tableArray.length);
    this.tableRows = this.tableRows.map(x => x.split(','));
  }
}
```

In HTML ,

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let tableHeaders of tableHeader">{{tableHeaders}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let tableRow of tableRows">
            <td *ngFor="let item of tableRow">{{ item }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Janardhan. But the array structure is different in my case. Can you please check the array structure in my post?

Comment: I made the below changes and its working fine.<tr *ngFor="let item of tableRows; let i = index">
                                <td *ngFor="let cell of item">
                                  {{ cell }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in

`this.tableRows =  this.tableArrayRows.split(',');`

You are missing the tableArrayRows array position to split. If that's the problem something like:

`this.tableRows =  this.tableArrayRows[this.tableArrayRows.length - 1].split(',');`

Should fix it.

Comment: No its not fixed the problem .I am getting empty rows after changing the code.